# Numbers don't wrap to new line in fixed width

Tags: html, css

I have two `<div>`. One of them with 'Lorem ipsum' text, second - with numbers. I found, that `div` with numbers, don't wrap numbers to new line in fixed width `<div>`. Is anybody can explain, why number don't wrap to new line, maybe this situation described somewhere in specifications?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AleshaOleg/8sysjhvm).

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusantium quasi consequatur nobis magni molestias repudiandae rerum quisquam quo dolore dolorem! Sit eligendi accusamus aliquam consectetur inventore minima, fugiat qui quia.</div>
<div>111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111</div>
```

Comment: If numbers don't have a space they won't wrap to a new line and you will end up overflowing content. Try adding a space in the middle of your string of numbers and you will see them drop to a new line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the browser treats numerals as regular text and won't break it unless you tell it to with something like the [`word-wrap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-wrap) or [`word-break`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break) property. Add a rule like:

```
div {
  width: 200px;
  word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

to do that.

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/8sysjhvm/1/)**

Comment: So, basically I should give this rule to each fixed width div in my pages? Is it bad or good practice? Because I don't know, maybe somewhere, anybody wants to create a header with numbers only, and then my page will broke down.

Comment: If the content of those divs could overflow as in your example, then I'd say sure.

Answer (score 1):

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusantium quasi consequatur nobis magni molestias repudiandae rerum quisquam quo dolore dolorem! Sit eligendi accusamus aliquam consectetur inventore minima, fugiat qui quia.</div>
<div>111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111</div>
```

Comment: right answer, but no explanation, can't upwote this one. Sorry:(